# Get only those instances that have other instances related to it in Sequelize with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Suppose I have two models in Sequelize, VideoCategories, and Videos, where:

```
        VideoCategory.hasMany(models.Video, {
            foreignKey: 'categoryId'
        });
and
        Video.belongsTo(models.VideoCategory, {
            foreignKey: 'categoryId',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
```

I want to select all those categories that have videos related to them.
In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "name" FROM "VideoCategories" c INNER JOIN "Videos" v ON v."videoCategoryId" = c."id"
```

But with Sequelize, how would it be?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Might need to play around with it a bit. The sequelize.fn part gives you the DISTINCT that you are looking for. The required: true piece of the include object makes an inner join, rather than a left join.

```
VideoCategory.findAll({
    attributes: [sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('VideoCategory.name'))]
    include: [{
        model: Video,
        required: true
    }]
})
```